# Regular expression for any number of characters unlimited but should allow only 12 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing difficulty in regular expression.

The requirement is a regular expression for any number of characters unlimited, but should allow only `12` numbers {digits}.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this:

```
var s = '12345aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabc444';

var maxDigits = 12,
    len = s.length,
    numDigits = 0,
    newLen;


if (len > maxDigits) {
    newLen = s.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').length;
    numDigits = len - newLen;
}

if (numDigits > maxDigits) {
    //error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think this regex would do the trick:

```
/^(.*?[\d].*?){12}$/
```

You are doing an ungreedy match for any number of characters on either side of a digit.  That subpattern must be present 12 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]{12}
```

Try this... This will provide you 12 digits. 12 and only 12.

now you need to add any char but not numbers, need help?

Answer (score 0):

Example for matching 3 digits in a string:

```
/^(([^\d]*\d[^\d]*){3})$/.test('asd1a2a4a') // -> (3 digits) true
/^(([^\d]*\d[^\d]*){3})$/.test('asd1a2a44a') // -> (4digits) false
```